# Creating a custom directive for cross field validation(confirm password) in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-directive

I have created a component(set-pass),I want to perform password and confirm password activities in this component.I have tried it by creating a custom directive(confirm-equal-validator.directive.ts) inside shared folder.

Below are my component files

set-pass.component.html

```
    <form >
      <mat-form-field >
        <input matInput name="password" placeholder="New password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'" [formControl]="passFormControl" required>

        <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
        <mat-error *ngIf="passFormControl.hasError('required')">
            Please enter your newpassword
          </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field >
        <input matInput name="confirmPassword"  appConfirmEqualValidator="password"  placeholder="Confirm password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'" [formControl]="confirmFormControl" #confirmPasswordControl="ngModel" required>

        <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
        <mat-error *ngIf="confirmFormControl.hasError('required')">
          Confirm your password
          </mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="confirmFormControl.hasError('notEqual')">
            Confirm your password
            </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
   </form>
```

set-pass.component.ts

```
    import {Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, Validators} from 
         '@angular/forms';
    import {ErrorStateMatcher} from '@angular/material/core';

     @Component({
       selector: 'ylb-set-pass',
       templateUrl: './set-pass.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./set-pass.component.css']
       })
     export class SetPassComponent {

        passFormControl = new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
         ]);
           confirmFormControl = new FormControl('', [
          Validators.required,
        ]);
   }
```

confirm-equal-validator.directive.ts(present inside shared folder)

```
    import { Validator,AbstractControl,NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Directive,Input} from '@angular/core';



    @Directive({
       selector: '[appConfirmEqualValidator]',
       providers: [{
            provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
            useExisting: ConfirmEqualValidatorDirective ,
            multi:true
        }]
     })

   export class ConfirmEqualValidatorDirective implements Validator{
     @Input() appConfirmEqualValidator:string;
      validate(control: AbstractControl):{[key:string]:any} | null{
        const controlToCompare = 
    control.parent.get(this.appConfirmEqualValidator);
        if(controlToCompare && controlToCompare.value !== control.value){
           return{'notEqual':true};
         }
         return null;
       }
     }
```

I have imported this component in app.module.ts like this

```
    import { ConfirmEqualValidatorDirective } from './shared/confirm-equal-validator.directive';
```

I have followed every steps properly given in this video

```
    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhazkQd59Hk
```

Ended up with this error in CMD

```
    ERROR in src/main.ts(5,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module './environments/environment'.
```

I want to achieve confirm password  through material components only,
like this

[image]

Comment: this not related to custom directive somwhere in your component you have imported environment file that is why it is showing this error

Comment: I have not imported any environment file

Comment: open `main.ts` and check your imports.

Comment: Ya it has been imported like this  import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

Comment: Should i need to remove this path?

Comment: no, you should remove `environment` imports in `main.ts`.

Answer (score 1):

Your error put aside, there's a much easier way of checking if passwords are matching.

Given you have two form controls like you do :

```html
<input matInput name="password" placeholder="New password" [formControl]="passFormControl" required (blur)="checkPasswordControls()">
<input matInput name="password" placeholder="Confirm password" [formControl]="confirmFormControl" required (blur)="checkPasswordControls()">
```

```js
checkPasswordControls() {
  if (this.passFormControl.value !== this.confirmFormControl.value) {
    this.passFormControl.setErrors({ notEqual: true });
    this.confirmFormControl.setErrors({ notEqual: true });
  } else {
    this.passFormControl.setErrors(this.passFormControl.errors ? { ...this.passFormControl.errors } : null);
    this.confirmFormControl.setErrors(this.confirmFormControl.errors ? { ...this.confirmFormControl.errors } : null);
  }
}
```

Now everytime you leave either input, your component will check if the value of the two forms match : if not, it will set an error on both inputs.

This allows you to remove your directive (and since you use this directive only once, you don't need a directive), is shorter to read, is clearer and more easier to understand.

Comment: An elegant and minimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find module './environments/environment' check whether in current directory you have any folder named environment ie.. , **src>app>environment>environment.ts,environment.prod.ts**
The problem is your main module has a dependency on environment folder and its not present ,mostly if you are using vscode or some other smart editor the un resolved directory errors is picked up in the editor itself.

Comment: there is no such file in src>app

Comment: then comment this line.